# How do I install motorbike frame and swingarm protectors?

Tags: motorcycle, frame, swingarm, track

I am considering the purchase of frame and swingarm protectors for my track bike. Just to give you an idea, below are sample pictures of frame (left) and swingarm (right) protectors taken at random from the internet:

[image: frame protector]
[image: swingarm]

These seem to be clipped onto the part they are supposed to protect. However, I am not sure if they are glued or not. In other words, how do I install motorbike frame and swingarm protectors?

Comment: Did they come with instructions?

Comment: @SolarMike Haven't bought them yet, but I can't find instructions on the vendor website.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention the particular brand you're buying, but some motorbike frame protectors come with bolts that are meant to substitute the ones in the frame. They are longer than the originals, allowing you to install the protector on the part of the bolt that remain on the outside of the frame.

I'm not sure about the swingarm, but should be straightforward too. Probably you have to disassembly the rear axis and while assembling back put the swingarm protector before the chain tensioner.

Can't help much without knowing the particular model you intend to buy, but I'm pretty confident whichever it is they are not glued. I wouldn't trust them if they were at least..

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the brand is irrelevant since all the designs are pretty much the same: they have to follow the lines and spacings dictated by the shape of the frame. Not sure if the protectors are fastened with bolts either as this would require replacing existing critical fittings i.e. frame bolts with longer ones to accommodate for the extra space within the flanged joint.

Comment: You didn't mention the motorcycle model in the question and the slider design will depend on the bike it's made for. Some bikes might provide another mean of fitting the slider besides substituting a frame bolt, but that's usually the way I've seem it being done.